# brew install coreutils failing 10.9.5 OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, gnu-coreutils

It has been 2 days that I have failed to install `coreutils`.

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/Mehdi/Library/Logs/Homebrew/coreutils/03.make:

src/ginstall -c
-m 644 'man/unlink.1' '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/share/man/man1/gunlink.1'   src/ginstall -c src/uniq '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/bin/./guniq'  src/ginstall -c -m 644 'man/vdir.1' '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/share/man/man1/gvdir.1' src/ginstall -c src/unlink '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/bin/./gunlink'   src/ginstall -c src/vdir '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/bin/./gvdir'  src/ginstall
-c -m 644 'man/wc.1' '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/share/man/man1/gwc.1'  src/ginstall
-c -m 644 'man/whoami.1' '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/share/man/man1/gwhoami.1'   src/ginstall -c src/wc '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/bin/./gwc'  src/ginstall -c -m 644 'man/yes.1' '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/share/man/man1/gyes.1'   src/ginstall -c src/whoami '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/bin/./gwhoami'   src/ginstall -c src/yes '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/bin/./gyes'   src/ginstall
-c src/ginstall '/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.27/bin' make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2 make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1 make:
*** [install] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.9. We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version. You may encounter build failures or other breakages. Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

Comment: Error at the bottom is pretty clear. Your system might be outside the support window for Homebrew. If you can't upgrade, you may need to do a source install.

Comment: How can I make a source install of coreutils ?

Comment: A) Get source. B) Follow compilation and installation instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in Clemens’ answer, Homebrew doesn’t support macOS 10.9. You can either:

- Try [TigerBrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew), a fork of Homebrew for old macOS versions
- Install `coreutils` from source, with something like the following:

  ```
  wget https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/coreutils/coreutils-8.25.tar.xz
  tar xJf coreutils-8.25.tar.xz
  cd coreutils-8.25/
  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid question but why are you still running OS 10.9? The current version is 10.12 and 10.13 will become out pretty soon. I'm not sure if this is related in any way to your issue but even the error message tells you that you "may encounter build failures or other breakages".

In short: Unless you have a very good reason not to (e.g. some apps that don't run on newer versions of macOS), **I suggest updating to macOS 10.12** and see if it works there.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Clemens but I'm pretty sure there is a way to make it right with my current version...

Comment: I can only go by what's in the [coreutils Homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/coreutils.rb#L41-L45) which only lists Yosemite, El Capitan and Sierra but not Mavericks (yours). If you look at the version history, [Mavericks was removed last November](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/f3b06a6932a23dd78962eda45885693e972a23d2) – so it might not be supported by the current version of coreutils. You could maybe try installing 8.25 – which seems to be the last officially supported version.