# Install CocoaPods on an old Mac

Tags: ios, macos, unity-game-engine, cocoapods, osx-lion

I'm using the Unity 5.2.4f game development engine and I have installed Ruby 1.9.3 on my old Mac with a [Mac OS X v10.7.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion) system on it.

When I open a Unity project for the first time, there is an installation attempt which is failing and I don't know how to solve this, after trying for a few days. Here is the error I get:

```
    IOS RESOLVER

Failed to install Cocoapods for the current user.

It will not be possible to install Cocoapods in the generated Xcode project which will result in link errors when building your application.

For more information see:
  https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html


'gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6 --user-install' failed with code (1):


WARNING:  You don't have /Users/DAN26/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
    gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  Error installing activesupport:
  i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

So I go to the Terminal and do the following:

```
export PATH="/Users/DAN26/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin:$PATH"
```

No change. So I do this:

```
export PATH="/Users/DAN26/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:$PATH"
```

Still get the same message...

```
Enter

    $PATH

Result:

    -bash: /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/Users/DAN26/.rbenv/bin:/Users/DAN26/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/DAN26/.rvm/bin: No such file or directory
```

I have installed lower versions of activesupport 4.2.5 and cocoapods 0.34.4 but no change (I *have* installed them because any other versions require Ruby 2.0.0+ which I fail to install)

Also if I enter in the Terminal:

```
gem list
```

I get this:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (4.2.9, 4.2.6, 4.2.5, 3.2.22.5)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
claide (0.7.0)
cocoapods (0.34.4)
cocoapods-core (0.34.4)
cocoapods-downloader (0.7.2)
cocoapods-plugins (0.3.2)
cocoapods-trunk (0.3.1)
cocoapods-try (0.4.5)
colored (1.2)
escape (0.0.4)
fuzzy_match (2.0.4)
i18n (0.8.6)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.8.6, 1.5.5)
json_pure (1.8.6)
minitest (5.10.3, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.12.1)
nap (1.1.0, 0.8.0)
netrc (0.7.8)
open4 (1.3.4)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tzinfo (1.2.3)
xcodeproj (0.19.4)
```

I don't have any understanding on Mac. All I did above was by tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo gem install cocoapods` for installing CocoaPods in an old mac. It will be asking for the administrator password.

Based on the upcoming error, do the below steps:

1. `sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6`
2. `sudo gem install cocoapods`

It can be possible you have to check activesupport version with [this link](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions).

Comment: If its working please accept the answer. Though other SO visitors can solve their issue with applying above command.

Comment: I have tried your answer and got this: `ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
 cocoapods-core requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.`

Comment: I did the steps in your updated answer and got the same error after trying install cocoapods. I have tried to install Ruby 2.0.0 and got error says `Installing required packages: coreutils... Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install coreutils'`

Comment: Have tried to install coreutils from soruce by this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020830/8085852) but after trying again install ruby get the same error for coreutils

Comment: @JavaBroker Did you find a solution for you issue?

Comment: @JuneWang I don't remember.  I think Ruby v2 solved it. You can read the later topic I created here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903782/install-ruby-2-0-0-on-an-old-mac-os-10-7-5-lion